# How to use signal event of libevent in correct way

Tags: linux, multithreading, signals, libevent

[libevent](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref4_event.html) supports to notify when watched signals arrived. It seems that the signals could interrupt at anywhere of the code on Linux/Unix (**Is it right?**) . Does it mean that, I should check the return value and `errno` is equal `EINTR` after invoked all system calls and other library functions?
There is the simple test code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
int i = 0;
void handle(int signo)
{
    printf("i[%d], signo[%d]\n", i, signo);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, handle);
    while (1) {
        i++;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

After run this code, and press several **Ctrl+C**, get the following output:

```
 ./signal 
^Ci[475151517], signo[2]
^Ci[656118185], signo[2]
^Ci[891673397], signo[2]
^Ci[1668347228], signo[2]
^Ci[-2123628990], signo[2]
```

It seems that `sigint` interrupts at `i++`. If the above conjecture is right, is it the right way to handle the signal like this:

- Call `pthread_sigmask` to block signal in main thread which runs event loop.
- Call `sigwait` to wait the signal in the watched thread, and notify the main thread by pipe.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a signal may interrupt execution anywhere (unless masked) and yes it means all system calls (I'm not sure if there are some exceptions though?) such as write/read/poll will return a EINT when interrupted by a signal (you may want to read the [man page for pselect](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pselect), particularly the 'BUGS' section). This is known as the ['PC loser-ing problem'](http://blog.reverberate.org/2011/04/eintr-and-pc-loser-ing-is-better-case.html)

You should use libevent native support for signal handling. Check out all the macros 'evsignal_xxx' [in their documentation](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-2.1/doxygen/html/event_8h.html).

In a nutshell, you do something like this:

```c
struct event ev_sigint;
struct event_base *ev_base;
ev_base = event_init();
evsignal_set(&ev_sigint, SIGINT, sighandler, ev_base);
evsignal_add(&ev_sigint, NULL);
event_dispatch();
```

Then from your signal handler you break the loop:

```c
void sighandler(int signal, short events, void *base)
{
    event_base_loopbreak(base);
}
```

Comment: Refer to [man page signal(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/signal)，Some system calls, such as `read` from `inotify` are never restarted, regardless of the use of `SA_RESTART`(which is done in **libevent**). So if I need to resume from the signal handler, I have to check the error code for such interfaces. Use thread to `sigwait` for the signal and notify to main thread seems to be a better solution?